# Use and create kubernetes providers dynamically for another module

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create several k8s clusters in different regions in GCP, which goes essentially like this  (https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/master/examples/simple_regional_with_kubeconfig/main.tf)

```
locals {
  cluster_type = "simple-regional"
}

data "google_client_config" "default" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.gke.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.gke.ca_certificate)
}

module "gke" {
  source                 = "../../"
  project_id             = var.project_id
  name                   = "${local.cluster_type}-cluster${var.cluster_name_suffix}"
  regional               = true
  region                 = var.region
  network                = var.network
  subnetwork             = var.subnetwork
  ip_range_pods          = var.ip_range_pods
  ip_range_services      = var.ip_range_services
  create_service_account = false
  service_account        = var.compute_engine_service_account
  skip_provisioners      = var.skip_provisioners
}

module "gke_auth" {
  source = "../../modules/auth"

  project_id   = var.project_id
  location     = module.gke.location
  cluster_name = module.gke.name
}
```

Now this works fine, also when I use a for_each loop to create several clusters. Now my next aim is to deploy via helm charts certain things into the clusters. For this, I wrote a module whose `main.tf` looks as follows:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-first-namespace"
  }

  provider = kubernetes
}
```

and I call that module in the primary `main.tf` as follows:

```
module "helm_general" {
  source = "../../modules/helm_general"

  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait]
  for_each = module.gke

  providers {
    kubernetes = provider "kubernetes" {
      cluster_ca_certificate = each.value.ca_certificate
      host                   = each.value.host
      token                 = each.value.client_token
    }
  }
}
```

Yet, Terraform keeps telling me

```
│ Error: Missing newline after argument
│
│   on main.tf line 109, in module "helm_general":
│  109:     kubernetes = provider "kubernetes" {
│
│ An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

I already tried to bring in the credentials for each cluster as variables into the module and to setup the provider in the module, but Terraform kept telling me that providers cannot be instantiated in modules that are called with for_each.

Hence, my question is whether there is a way to do this dynamically as can deal with an unlimited number of k8s clusters and I do not want to write it down for each cluster explicitly in the `main.tf` file.

Many thanks for your input.

**Addition:**

When I try to run

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  for_each = module.gke

  cluster_ca_certificate = each.value.ca_certificate
  host                   = each.value.host
  token                 = each.value.client_token
}
```

in `main.tf` I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Reserved argument name in provider block
│
│   on main.tf line 103, in provider "kubernetes":
│  103:   for_each = module.gke
│
│ The provider argument name "for_each" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.
╵
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I don't think this can work. One, there is a syntax error because it has to be `providers = { ... }` and two because it can only use provider aliases: https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly.

Comment: @MarkoE Many thanks for getting back to me. I am aware, that the current setup does not work. I am rather asking myself whether there is some way we can create provider items for various kuibernetes clusters and apply them dynamically?

Comment: As I've mentioned, you could try to create provider alias configurations using the same `for_each` logic, but I have never tried that so it might not work. Then, in the `providers = {...}` you could reference the instances of `kuberentes` provider configurations by the key. Something like that. :)

Comment: Hi @MarkoE I tried this (see my addition of the question). Do you know how to fix that? :)

Comment: Ah, ok, which Terraform version are you using? :)

Comment: Terraform v1.0.5, is it too old?

Comment: I updated to v1.2.3, but still the error persists

Comment: Well, I thought that would solve it. I guess you will have to hardcode different aliases for different provider configurations.